# Chart requests vs assignments per week

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am struggling with something that I think must be simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. I want to use Power BI to chart requests vs assignments per week. I have the dates requests were logged and the date they were assigned.

I want a chart to show per calendar week, how many requests came in that week and how many were assigned that week.

Some sample data:

Logged:

```
03-Jul-23
03-Jul-23
03-Jul-23
03-Jul-23
03-Jul-23
03-Jul-23
03-Jul-23
03-Jul-23
03-Jul-23
03-Jul-23
03-Jul-23
03-Jul-23
03-Jul-23
03-Jul-23
```

Assigned:

```
11-Jul-23
04-Jul-23
11-Jul-23
11-Jul-23
11-Jul-23
11-Jul-23
04-Jul-23
04-Jul-23
11-Jul-23
04-Jul-23
11-Jul-23
11-Jul-23
11-Jul-23
04-Jul-23
```

I tried charting them in a clustered column but they group by either the log date or assign date. I think I need an absolute date reference (from a date table maybe) and I tried that also but can't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating two relationships between the Calendar dimension and the event fact tables. One relationship is between Calendar[Date] and Event[LogDate] and the other is between Calendar[Date] and Event[AssignDate]. Then I created two simple measures:

```
Assigned Count = CALCULATE(
                    COUNTROWS('Events'),
       USERELATIONSHIP(DimDate[Date], Events[Assigned])
)
```

and

```
Logged Count = CALCULATE(
                    COUNTROWS('Events'),
USERELATIONSHIP(DimDate[Date],Events[Logged])
)
```

then all the "logged" ones show up on the logged date, and the "Assigned" ones show up on the assigned date. After that everything is simple. Then you can just reuse those measures if you need to when creating other measures (like if you need to date-shift one).

Comment: this works. I figured part of it out but applying the USERELATIONSHIP to both measures (not just the inactive one) is important!

Comment: Yes, crucial step!

Comment: I have another related request ! Now I can show the count of requests in each week and count of assignments made each week. But I would also like to display a running sum of the unassigned requests. I would like to do that with a line and clustered column chart. The line showing the unassigned. I currently have  a calculation for unassigned which counts 1 if there is no assigned date and 0 if there is a date i.e. Reqsnotass = If(ISBLANK('Form'[WeekNumAssigned]),"1","0") . Can you help to incorporate this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the calendar (date) table as a reference table. Create a table called "DateTable" with a single column named "Date". Populate it with dates covering the entire period you want to analyze.
After creating the table, mark it as a Date table by right-clicking on the table in Fields pane > `Mark as Date Table`.

Since you have two date columns (Logged and Assigned), you'll need two relationships: one for the `Logged` date and one for the `Assigned` date.

Then in your original data table, create a new column called "LoggedWeek" :

```
LoggedWeek = FORMAT('YourDataTable'[Logged],"dd-mmm-yyyy") & " - " & FORMAT(DATEADD('YourDataTable'[Logged],6,DAY),"dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

Similarly for a "AssignedWeek" column :

```
AssignedWeek = FORMAT('YourDataTable'[Assigned],"dd-mmm-yyyy") & " - " & FORMAT(DATEADD('YourDataTable'[Assigned],6,DAY),"dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

Create measures to count the number of logged and assigned requests:

```
LoggedCount = COUNT('YourDataTable'[Logged])

AssignedCount = COUNT('YourDataTable'[Assigned])
```

For the Axis, use the Date from your DateTable.
For Values, use the measures you created: LoggedCount and AssignedCount.
Make sure to adjust the Axis to represent data in weeks. Under the Visualizations pane, select the x-axis and adjust the type to "Week".

Comment: thanks but I am getting an error that "A date column containing duplicate dates was specified in the call to function 'DATEADD'. This is not supported.

Comment: I solved by putting .[date] ..... i.e.    LoggedWeek = FORMAT('YourDataTable'[Logged].[date],"dd-mmm-yyyy") & " - " & FORMAT(DATEADD('YourDataTable'[Logged].[date],6,DAY),"dd-mmm-yyyy")

Comment: it is not working - the assigned count is returning all rows in my table for every week.

Comment: Can you share your dataset and model ? I don't like making assumptions

Comment: yes but I will need to strip it back to remove any sensitive info

Comment: maybe another way to do it .... I have calculated the week number for each logged date and assigned date using the WEEKNUM function. So for each row I have columns with the week number it was requested and the week number it was assigned. Is it possible to have a chart showing how many in each of those columns with each number (1-52) ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may want to look into is creating a Calendar or Date dimension to your data model. You can do it in PowerQuery or in DAX... and since I'm better at DAX, I'll go that route.
if you have a fact table with one date column, it's super easy... you can just use a table-valued function to create it:

```
CALENDAR(
    MINX('FactTable',[DateColumn]),
    MAXX('FactTable',[DateColumn])
   )
```

You can add whatever columns you like to your Calendar table, like this:

```
DimDate = 
  ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDAR(
        MIN(MINX('Events',[Assigned]),MINX('Events',[Logged])),
        MAX(MAXX('Events',[Assigned]),MAXX('Events',[Logged]))
    ),
    "WeekNumber", WEEKNUM([Date]),
    "MonthNumber",MONTH([Date]),
    "Year",YEAR([Date])
```

)

and then you can add whatever columns you want (like IsWeekend etc)... That way, you can group and filter your data really easily.

Comment: yes I had done this using DAX also!

Answer (score 0):

> But I would also like to display a running sum of the unassigned
> requests.

This is where you reuse your original count measure:

```
RT Assigned Count = CALCULATE([**UN**assigned Count],
                    FILTER(ALL('DimDate'),'DimDate'[Date]<=MAX('DimDate'[Date]))
                )
```

Comment: thank you, presume I need to put the USERELATIONSHIP on this also ?

Comment: also I don't think it is quite working, it is giving me the sum total of all assignments. I want the running total of unassigned items

Comment: Then you need to use the [Unassigned Count] measure instead of your [Assigned Count] measure inside that running sum.

Comment: Chart is showing the same (current) sum of unassigned requests for each week ... I am using Unassigned Count = CALCULATE(sum('Form'[Reqsnotass]),FILTER(ALL('Date'),'Date'[Date]<=MAX('Date'[Date])), USERELATIONSHIP('Date'[Week Number],'Form'[Reqsnotass]))
and 
Reqsnotass = If(ISBLANK('Form'[WeekNumAssigned]),"1","0")

Comment: I think it may be the Filter Date part that isn't working correctly. What exactly is that trying to achieve ?

Comment: You need FILTER() to create the running total. Look up Running Total on daxpatterns.com

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks @Pieter
With your help and the help from Amira, I have managed to get this working to my satisfaction.

I used DAX :

```
 Unassigned running total = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Form'[Reqsnotass]),
    FILTER(ALL('Date'[Week Number]),'Date'[Week Number]<=max('Date'[Week Number])), 
    USERELATIONSHIP('Date'[Week Number],'Form'[WeekNumRequested])
    )
```

And the output is what I had envisaged!

[image: My Chart]